# ionic serve complains about valid javascript "Parsing error: Unexpected token ="

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a vuex-orm model called Profile.js

```js
import { Model } from '@vuex-orm/core'

export default class Profile extends Model {
    static entity = 'profile'

    static fields () {
        return {
            id: this.uid(),
            // etc...
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `ionic serve` I get the following output:

```
Build finished at 14:20:05 by 0.000s
[INFO] Browser window opened to http://localhost:4200!
ERROR in 
[vue-cli-service] /home/user/IonicProjects/ionic/iloveu/src/store/models/Profile.js
[vue-cli-service]   4:19  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =
[vue-cli-service] 
[vue-cli-service] ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
[vue-cli-service] 
[vue-cli-service] webpack compiled with 1 error
```

So it complains about this line

```js
static entity = 'profile'
```

which is perfectly valid javascript or ecmascript.

What can I do so this valid code is not being tagged as erroneous?

my .eslintrc

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  'extends': [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
    'prettier'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020
  },
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'vue/no-deprecated-slot-attribute': 'off'
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: [
        '**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)',
        '**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)'
      ],
      env: {
        jest: true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

reference to the [vuex-orm documentation](https://vuex-orm.org/guide/model/defining-models.html#entity-name)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is the culprint

```
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020
  },
```

changing it to

```
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2022
  },
```

does not return this error anymore, which is weird because the Quasar framework uses ecmaVersion: 2018 and does not have this error.